# Oracle DB Job Scheduler

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, job-scheduling

I would like to create a scheduled job that will every 1st day of the month.

Below is the job that I manually run every 1st day of the month:

```
his_proc_mduniverse.md_proc_universe(v_date1, v_date2)
```

Example:

```
his_proc_mduniverse.md_proc_universe('01-JAN-2014' , '31-JAN-2014')
```

Given that I need to populate the starting and end dates every month, how can I implement this via job schedule?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Job for this task:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name        => 'my_new_job1',
   job_type        => 'plsql_block',
   job_action      => 'BEGIN his_proc_mduniverse.md_proc_universe(TRUNC(SYSDATE, ''month''), TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))); END;',
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1',
   enabled         => TRUE,
   auto_drop       => FALSE,
   comments        => 'every 1st day of the month');
END;
/
```

EDIT: To run at specified time (eg. 5 am) change `repeat_interval` to:

```
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1;BYHOUR=5;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0',
```

*Documentation:*

- [Using the Scheduler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/scheduse.htm)
- [CREATE_JOB Procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_sched.htm#999617)
- [TRUNC (date)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)
- [LAST_DAY (date)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. However, I got a few questions. So you're saying that this will work all year long? Also, where can I set it to run every 5 am on the 1st day of every month?

Comment: This works until you drop or disable job. Also see modified answer how to run at 5 am on the 1st day of every month.